# How to tally multiple inputs in a .txt and not just one

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have found a code that will tally up a list of values in a .txt file. However, for some reason it will only tally the first value that appears. So if the file has something like:

```
1
2
2
3
2
4
```

Then it will only print:

```
Final Tally
1:1

The program will automatically shut down in 5 minutes.
```

Full code:

```
    vote = input('Enter your vote: ')
    file = open('votedata.txt', 'a')
    file.write(vote + '\n')
    print('The system is adding your vote. The next person can vote in 3 seconds.')
    time.sleep(3)
    if vote == 'tally':
        break
#end of loop, beginning of tally
from collections import defaultdict
frequencies = defaultdict(int)
for number in open('votedata.txt'):
    frequencies[int(number)] += 1

for number in sorted(frequencies.keys()):
    print(' ')
    print('Final Tally:')
    print(number, ':', frequencies[number])
    print(' ')
    print('The program will automatically shut down in 5 minutes.')
    time.sleep(300)
```

How can I write it so that it collects and tallies every integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While pandas works, I kinda think it is overkill for something as simple as this.

```
with open("votedata.txt") as fp:
    results = {}
    for row in fp:
        try:
          v = int(float(row))
          if v not in results:
            results[v] = 0
          results[v] += 1
        except:
          print("Invalid Numeric entry")

print( results )
```

This is simple, doesn't load extra libraries, processes the results and if a user enters some junk data, it prints an error without actively interrupting the program workflow.

Comment: I can be the same at times but it has a lot more to that lib.  Adding an additioinal library means things need too be retained.   An issue I have with a current client is that they gave me old code, with no understanding of pd, and now im trying to sift through the version they are running to get things working, while I would much rather have just solved it simply, agnostic of an additionoal framework.  but they want modern access so i am not fiinding their versioin of pd anymore as much as doing a pd conversion from 0.25 to 1.0.1.

Keeping is as simple as possible for a new Dev is ideal.

Comment: ahh i see make sense

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can do this for you

```
df = pd.read_csv('votedata.txt', names=['votes'])
df['votes'].value_counts().to_dict()
```

`{2: 3, 4: 1, 3: 1, 1: 1}`

In your code:

```
import pandas as pd

    vote = input('Enter your vote: ')
    file = open('votedata.txt', 'a')
    file.write(vote + '\n')
    print('The system is adding your vote. The next person can vote in 3 seconds.')
    time.sleep(3)
    if vote == 'tally':
        break

df = pd.read_csv('votedata.txt', names=['votes'])
frequencies = df['votes'].value_counts().to_dict()

for number in sorted(frequencies.keys()):
    print(' ')
    print('Final Tally:')
    print(number, ':', frequencies[number])
    print(' ')
    print('The program will automatically shut down in 5 minutes.')
    time.sleep(300)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over all output, so after 5 minutes you'll get second result :)

You just need to remove indent from last three lines.